# Purchase.wasParchased returns falls in Google Internal Testing

Tags: in-app-purchase, codenameone, google-play-console

Internal testing with google-play use to give "TRUE" values for Purchased.wasPurchased() method if purcahased. However, after "publishing app", new "internal tests" for new versions do not give TRUE for the waspurchased method.

Ofcourse the wasPurcahsed method works fine in Codenameone Simulator.

Did anyone encounter this?

Comment: This could be a regression with the new API level change. Did you explicitly define a play API level in the build hints?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I dont think I played with any play API in the build hints.

Comment: Just took a quick look through the code for wasPurchased() to see if anything jumps out.  A couple of questions:
1. Are you receiving the itemPurchased() callback correctly in your app's main class?
2. Where/when are you calling wasPurchased()?  If it is inside the itemPurchased() callback it is possible that it won't actually return true yet.

Comment: Actually, I also have a refresh button that reads wasPurchased to double check even after I get a response call back to itemPurchased. So practically., I dont depend on the call back, still my button click returns all false values. I havenot tested if my PUBLISHED app has the same issue,  or is only in the internal testing app track release, i will try to buy$$ a product using the official published app, and get back to you, currently seems impossible to buy my own in app purchases using the same phone I use for internal testing. Google only shows me the internal test app.

Comment: I assume you've probably read this already, but my series of blog posts on in-app purchase from a while back might be helpful.  When writing these posts, I had to deal with all of the hoops of Google and Apple for testing.  I remember it being a little bit complicated - needing to set up "dummy" test accounts etc...  https://www.codenameone.com/blog/intro-to-in-app-purchase.html